# PayPal Prestahop currencies conversion

Tags: paypal, prestashop

I am using [Prestahop 1.5](http://prestashop.com) and want to use [PayPal](http://paypal.com) module for receiving payments, but **Croatian kuna (HRK)** is not supported,
So I am trying to find a way to convert from **HRK** to **dollar** before processing it to PayPal.

Did anyone have success in this?
Or knows how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one prestashop forum discussion for same issue with unsupported currency:

in paypal module express_checkout/process.php line 102

```
$this->currency = new Currency((int)$this->context->cart->id_currency);
```

change to:

```
$this->currency = new Currency((int)$this->context->cart->id_currency=2);
```

where 2 is currency id

You should find USD currency ID and replace it in this example. I didn't tested this, but it's worth a try.